# Springdoc OpenAPI UI Documentation

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Is it possible to generate swagger ui documentation using interfaces rather than controller classes which implement the those interfaces?

Putting the documentation in the implementation class makes it look cluttered.
Springfox had this option, is it available in springdoc? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You just add the OpenAPI annotations on the interface level. An it just works.

This is a sample working demo and the annotation are on the interface level as well:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc